# User Input Case Insensitive

Tags: javascript, case-insensitive

I want only the users [Alice and Bob to be greeted](http://jsbin.com/gajoha/2/). But I want Alice's and Bob's input to be case insensitive (i.e. Alice, alice, ALICE, AlicE, etc).

```
var name = prompt("What's your name?");

var user1 = "Alice", user2 = "Bob";

if (name == user1) { alert("Hi " + user1); } 
else if (name == user2) { alert("Hi " + user2); }
else { alert("You're neither Alice nor Bob."); }
```

I've read through a ton of posts but none of them made sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In future, please tag questions with the language you're using. I added `javascript` this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your input and the string you are testing against to a common case (either lower or uppercase) before testing them.

If you are using Javascript:

```
if (name.toLowerCase() == user1.toLowerCase())
{
    alert("Hi " + user1);
}
...
```

Other languages will have similar functions to convert the case of your string.

Comment: It worked! Thank you.

The mistake I was making was this:

if (name == user1.toLowerCase()) { alert("Hi " + user1.toLowerCase()); }

And that's why I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Convert the strings to lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) during comparison:

```
if (name.toLowerCase() === user1.toLowerCase()) {
    alert("Hi " + user1);
}
```

If you prefer, you can use [uppercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) if you wish.

If you have more than two names, it might be better to use an array:

```
var users = ['Alice', 'Bob'];
var u = users.indexOf(name.toLowerCase());

if (u > -1) {
    alert("Hi " + users[u]);
} else {
    alert("You're neither Alice nor Bob.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I'm curious. What does "if (u > -1)" mean and/or do? If you don't mind explaining?

I know it's calling the "u" is the variable. I don't know what "> -1" means.

Thanks again!

Comment: `u` is the index, or position, of the name in the `users` array. If it is equal to -1, it was not found in the array. If it is greater than -1, it is somewhere in the array.

Comment: Your "users" array should contain lowercase version of the names.